# Get Cat1/Cat2/Cat3 string from self referencing table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to yield a string that reads like Cat1/Cat2/Cat3, etc, from a self-referencing table.

Data looks like this:

CategoryTable

CategoryID, [Name], ParentID

1, Root, 0

2, Cat1, 1

3, Cat2, 2

4, Cat3, 3

5, Cat4, 1

6, Cat5, 5

I want to yield:

Root/Cat1/Cat2/Cat3
Root/Cat4/Cat5

How do I do this in sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CTE

[SQL Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d7eb/7)

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT CategoryID,CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(4000)) AS Name 
  FROM Category 
  WHERE ParentID = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.CategoryID, CAST(e.Name + '/' + c.Name AS VARCHAR(4000))
  FROM cte e
  INNER JOIN Category c 
    ON c.ParentID = e.CategoryID
)
SELECT c1.Name
FrOM cte c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte c2 where c1.name <> c2.name AND c2.name like c1.NAME + '%')
```

Comment: I think this will work. However, I get this error:  <br>
`Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4  <br>
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'a17c3c71-3634-41c2-b576-d13e8417ccc0' to data type int`  <br>Basically, the CategoryID and ParentID are guids. How can I handle conversion of that.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(255) --Or whatever length you need
SET @str = ''

SELECT @str = @str + [Name] + '/' FROM CategoryTable

SET @str = SUBSTRING(@str,0,LEN(@str)) -- remove the trailing '/'
PRINT @str
```